# Is there an ordinal satisfying $\xi$ = $\omega$+$\xi$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, ordinals

Given that $\omega$ is the $ord(\mathbb{N})$, I need to prove/disprove whether there is an ordinal $\xi$ satisfying the equation $\xi$ = $\omega$+$\xi$. Here, the order given is an anti-lexicographical order, i.e., $\omega$ $\not\approxeq$ $\omega$ $+$ $1$.

I believe that there is no such ordinal, as on the left hand side, there is no maximum element, but there would be one on the right hand side, if $\xi$ was finite. I am having trouble showcasing this even when $\xi$ is an infinite ordinal.

Any help would be appreciated- thanks!

Comment: What is the order type of $1 + \omega$? This is simply $\omega$. Can you use this to find such a $\xi$?

Comment: @Sven-OleBehrend Do you mean $\xi$ = $\omega$ would do? I thought the equation would only hold if the equation was : $\xi$ = $\xi$ + $\omega$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Sven-OleBehrend Oh I understand your hint now, having been reminded of the distributive law :P Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the ordinal $\omega\cdot\omega$, then we have that $\omega+\omega\cdot\omega=\omega\cdot(1+\omega)=\omega\cdot\omega$.

Now, if $\alpha\geq\omega\cdot\omega$ is any ordinal, then there is some $\beta$ such that $\omega\cdot\omega+\beta=\alpha$ (note that $\beta$ may be equal to $\alpha$, that's fine). But now, $\omega+\alpha=\omega+\omega\cdot\omega+\beta=\omega\cdot\omega+\beta=\alpha$.

So indeed, this holds for most ordinals.

Comment: This is even an *iff* state : if $\alpha = \omega + \alpha$, then by induction $\alpha = \omega  \cdot n + \alpha \geq \omega \cdot n$ for any finite ordinal $n$ and therefore $\alpha \geq \omega \cdot \omega$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I forgot about the left distributive law. I have one further question - would $\omega*\omega$ be a minimal such ordinal?

Comment: @JadenPark: Yes. Because any smaller ordinal has the form $\omega\cdot n+k$, so $\omega+\omega\cdot n+k=\omega\cdot(1+n)+k=\omega\cdot(n+1)+k$.

Comment: @JadenPark Yes, see SolubleFish's comment.